# Can't capture href tag content with regex first time

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping

I want to scrape a website for external links and paths by using regex on `href` html tag.

But I don't know if there is simpler way than my code:

```
import requests
import re

target_url = ("http://testphp.vulnweb.com/")

response = requests.get(target_url)
res = re.findall('href\=\"[\w.:/]+\"', response.content.decode("utf-8"))

for i in res:
    patt = re.compile("\"[.:/\w]+\"")
    not_raw = re.findall(patt, i)
    raw = re.findall("[.:/\w]+", not_raw[0])
    print(raw)
```

Is there a way, instead of using regex 3 times, to pick the path and links from an `href` tag without capturing it?
I mean the `res` variable output is like this:

```
href="https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/"
```

Can I use regex in a way to pick up the URL in the `res` variable like the following?

```
https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/
```

Comment: Probably because scraping HTML with regex is generally discouraged. Use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use "caputuring" and "non-capturing" matches. Example:

```
re.findall(r'(?:href=")([^\"]+)(?:")', response.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

The `?:` in `(?:href=")` means that this part will not be returned as part of the matched string.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html:

> (?:...)
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing `HTML` with regex is a poor choice. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) to learn why.

To get all the `href` attributes usa a `HTML` library like `BeautifulSoup` and try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://testphp.vulnweb.com/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").find_all("a", href=True)
href_ = [a["href"] for a in soup if "http" in a["href"]]
print("\n".join(href_))
```

Output:

```
https://www.acunetix.com/
https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/
http://www.acunetix.com
https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/php-security-scanner/
https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/prevent-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications/
http://www.eclectasy.com/Fractal-Explorer/index.html
http://www.acunetix.com
```